# style code in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myButton">My Button</button><br /><br />
        <span id="myPara"> My paragraph</span>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

below is code in `custom.css`

```
#myPara{
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

below is code in `custom.js`

```
$('#myButton','#myPara').on('click',function(){
    $(this).css('border-color','white').css('background','black').css('color','white');
});
```

I want to apply the given css as shown in the jquery code.

It also isn't giving any error in console, which makes it harder for me to find the error.

In my browser no css effect is showing on click.

I am a beginner in jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#myButton','#myPara').on('click',function(){
```

In this line, the first argument is a CSS selector and the second argument is used for context. You probably wanted this instead:

```
$('#myButton,#myPara').on('click',function(){
```

You can find out more about [how the `$()` function works here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Answer (score 4):

Youv'e coded it incorrectly...

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){
    $('#myPara').css({
        borderColor: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        color: 'white'});
});
```

Combine your CSS properties in jQuery proper formatting, and check the selector. In your jQuery `this` was referring to both the button and the paragraph.

```js
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){
        $('#myPara').css({
            borderColor: 'white',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            color: 'white'});
    });
```

```css
#myPara{
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">My Button</button><br /><br />
        <span id="myPara"> My paragraph</span>
```

If you want the change to happen when *either* the button **or** the paragraph is clicked, you need to alter the jQuery selector.... Note the quotes and comma in the selector. This will change whatever was clicked rather than just the paragraph each time.

```js
$('#myButton, #myPara').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css({
            borderColor: 'white',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            color: 'white'});
    });
```

```css
#myPara{
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">My Button</button><br /><br />
        <span id="myPara"> My paragraph</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `context` to a string, `"#myPara"` at `jQuery()` call. Use

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function() {
    $("#myPara")
    .css({borderColor:'white', background:'black', color:'white'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma should be inside the selector like

```
$('#myButton, #myPara').on('click',function(){ 
$(this).css('border-color','white').css('background','black').css('color','white'); 
});
```

Comment: You are correct in the syntax problem but your solution doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want "if the button is clicked, then #myPara changes color" This can be done with the code below:

```
    jQuery('#myButton').click(function(){
         jQuery('#myPara').addClass('active');
    });

    .active {
        border-color: white;
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }
```

Adding class seems like a more effective way to go about doing this. That way it is easier to add/remove/edit styles.